# Why is this audit spam?

Tags: discussion, spam, review-audits

I just received [this review audit](https://superuser.com/review/low-quality-posts/1019263) in the Low Quality Posts queue. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Yes, it is possible to setup. TCP tunneling Configuration of the tunnel is applied by the client which requests the session. VPN via AnyDesk provides a private network between two clients configuration for start IP-address and subnet mask can be changed in the settings dialog. Other options apart from Anydesk are Logmein, R-HUB remote support servers, Teamviewer, GotomyPC etc.]

I passed the audit, but only because I noticed that the user who posted it was deleted, so I opened the post in a new tab to see if it was an audit. If the user wasn't deleted, I would probably have pressed Looks OK and failed.

I don't see why this is spam. At first I thought it was promoting AnyDesk, but that's clearly not the case since [the question](https://superuser.com/q/1485417/513819) itself is about AnyDesk. Maybe the last sentence suggesting other options might be the part that's considered spam, but it suggests several other options and there are no links. If it were trying to promote one of those products, I would expect it to only mention the product it's promoting and link to it.

It also looks like an actual attempt to answer the question. The question asks "Is it possible to setup VPN through anydesk TCP Tunneling?" and the answer states "Yes, it is possible to setup". I don't know anything about the topic, so I can't tell whether or not this is a *good* answer, but even if it isn't [wrong answers shouldn't be deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563/4284627). All that matters in the Low Quality Posts queue is if it's an *attempt* to answer the question, and this answer clearly is.

I'm sure this was marked as spam for a good reason, but even after staring at it for half an hour I can't figure out what that reason is, so I definitely wouldn't expect other reviewers to pass this audit (unless they like me notice that the user is deleted). So could this answer please be removed from review audits? And I would also be curious to know why it was deleted as spam.

Comment: I'm not going into details, but there has a known R-HUB spam campaign going on for months. The post was deleted for spam roughly an hour after it being posted.

Comment: This is non-obvious for many reviewers and I don't think the post is useful as review. I strongly recommend removing it from the audit list.

Comment: We are working on [training spammers to post automated constructive comments](https://xkcd.com/810/) all we have to do now is to get them to stop hawking their product while they do it. R-HUB are known regular spammers.

Comment: I've removed the spam flags from the post, down voted and deleted it again. This *should*  remove it from the review queues ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This particular user (could be more than one, I suppose) keeps coming back and promoting the use of "R-HUB remote support servers" despite the moderators continuing to destroy their accounts. This trend spans across *years*.

Like [Mast mentions](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/14315/why-is-this-audit-spam#comment41807_14315), I'm not going to go into excessive details, but I will mention that the oldest post on Super User containing this type of spam has long since [been deleted](https://superuser.com/questions/655433/what-is-ideal-internet-speed-for-remote-desktop-connection/1110139#1110139) (10k+ link), and so has the user.

Should this type of spam be an audit? In my opinion, probably not. As you describe, it's relatively difficult to tell this is spam at first glance. You *were* paying attention enough to notice that the user had been deleted, though, so kudos!

Comment: I've removed the spam flags from the post, down voted and deleted it again. This *should*  remove it from the review queues ...

Comment: @DavidPostill Just encountered the same spam during a different audit: https://superuser.com/review/first-posts/1020667

Comment: @MMM A different post. That's been sorted as well. He is a prolific spammer.

Comment: "Should this type of spam be an audit?" Maybe you would be interested in this https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238647/213575

Comment: @Braiam Yes, I would indeed. Thanks for the mention.